# In C, Is there a quick way to check equality between a single array value and any of another array's values?

Tags: c, arrays, range, equality

I've been trying to find how to do this for hours. Is there a simple way to check if the value of an array is equal to any of the values in another array that has been dynamically allocated?

I don't have any real example code since my code is unable to do this regardless of what I've tried, but the general idea I'm trying to figure is:

```
if *whatsread[i] == dictionary[any value by checking all]//so if the current value  
                                          matches any value found in the dictionary array
    {
    execute this code;
    }
```

It seems so deceivingly simple I can't believe there isn't a simple way to do this. I've searched all over and haven't found a solid answer. I'm open to anything.

Also, the both arrays are char types and every value is a string.

Comment: Define "quick". As in, can be coded quickly? Or runs quickly?

Comment: Well coded quickly I suppose. Non complicated. @vanza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function for linear searching [`lfind`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lsearch.html) for this:

```
size_t nel = 0;
char *f = lfind(whatsread[i], dictionary, &nel, DICT_SIZE, (int(*)(const void*, const void*))strcmp);
if (f) {
     // f points to the entry 
} else {
     // Not found
}
```